# How to handle pins in A64-OLinuXino-1G4GW board using Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a project where we would like to use [A64-OLinuXino-1G4GW](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A64/A64-OLinuXino/open-source-hardware) board. There is a problem with pin handling of the board, as the programs I want to run are written in Python language and I have not found any library to control pins. I would greatly appreciate it if you could quote some library or some examples of python code for pin handling.
PS: The project started with raspberry pi board so it would be great if I could use same py files but with the appropriate library for [A64-OLinuXino-1G4GW](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A64/A64-OLinuXino/open-source-hardware) board.